# Python Selenium - Drag and drop in File Explorer of an application

Tags: python, .net, azure, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the python Chrome Selenium Driver to connect to the web portal of an .net application in an Azure Environment. I want to be able to drag and drop files from within in the File Explorer of the web portal; for example move files from one drive to another drive.

Is this possible? I can't use inspect to find the html of the File Explorer window.

Comment: Why can't you inspect the HTML?

Comment: As it's the File Explorer window of the application - so it's not HTML based.

Comment: What application? Java? Flash?

Comment: It's a .net application, in an Azure Environment